# How to convert a string to time/minutes in Birt report?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, timestamp, birt

I have string value stored in database say "4:30 PM" and I am fetching it in Birt. I want to convert this value to minutes. Is there any method/way(In birt/database) to do that ? (Other than splinting and adding)

P.S. : I want to find minutes difference between "4:30 PM" and 04:45 PM(IT STORED IN TIME).

F.Y.I. : I am using Postgres database.

Comment: Why don't you use datatype time for a time? Now you have have your first problem with datatypes and conversion, many more to come!

Comment: Actually it is "4:30 PM - 10:00 PM" stored in database and I am fetching split value from that.

Comment: Again, why don't use datatype time for a time? Use 2 columns if you have two different types of time (start and end) or a range type. Using varchar/text gives you horrible performance (no index possible) and many many problems because of all the workarounds.

Comment: Database was designed by database owner, I cannot do anything on that. Now I have to work on fetched data from database.

Comment: Talk to the data owner, he made a big mistake. Mistakes happen, but fix them as soon as possible, before you get into real deep trouble.

Comment: I agree with Frank: The DB should use two columns like START_DATE and END_DATE, both using a DATE/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP data type depending on your DB. Computing the time difference  is a snap then. However, it should also be noted that SQL doesn't have a time-only data type, thus if you *really* want to store the time only (without a date), then using a string is absolutely OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Frank comments, storing a string type to represent a Time value in a database is a very unefficient design. However sometimes we can't change this easily. Here is how to parse a such format in  BIRT.

Create a computed column in the dataset, set "Time" as dataType and enter as expression:

```
var dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a",java.util.Locale.ENGLISH);
dateFormat.parse(row["timeString"]);
```

Where "timeStr" is of course the name of your time column in that string format. If the dataset should handle large volumes, you could optimize this expression by intializing "dateFormat" only once in *beforeOpen* event.

For the second question, Birt has a native static function to get a difference in minutes:

```
BirtDateTime.diffMinute(time1, time2);
```

Comment: You should take into account the case when the end time is after midnight. That would result in a negative difference. Assuming that the end is on the next day, you should add 24 hours to the difference, then